# Differences between eigenstates, bound states and stationary states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, terminology, definition

I am not very clear about the differences between eigenstates, bound states and stationary states.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: Could you expand on what you *do* understand about them and *why* you have any confusion?

Comment: (i) Consider an electron in the ground state of Hydrogen. I understand that it is in bound state which is also a stationary state. So, what is the difference between these two terms?

(2) Consider an electron in the first exited state of Hydrogen atom. Can we call this a stationary state?

Answer (score 9):

For any operator $\hat A$ an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ is one for which:
$$\hat A|\psi\rangle=\lambda |\psi\rangle$$
Where $\lambda$ is a constant, and is called the eigenvalue of that state. If $\hat A$ is an observable, then $\lambda$ will be real.

A stationary state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltionain $\hat H$ (the energy operator). It is called stationary because when the system is in this state the expectation value $\langle \hat A \rangle$ of any operator $\hat A$ is time independent.

A bound state is one that does not go to infinity and is usually $0$ outside a given range of $(x,y,z)$. An example (in 1d) would be a $$\psi=e^{-|x|}$$ Which goes to $0$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$

Comment: The eigenvalue $\lambda$ can be complex if $\hat{A}$ is not Hermitian, and there is nothing wrong with non-Hermitian operators and their eigenvalues.

Comment: @rubenvb You are right, it was my assumption that $\hat A$ was an observable (and therefore Hermitian), when I get chance I will edit this in.

Comment: just making sure there's no operator discrimination going on here :p.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Eigen state* : Particular to an operator, which when operates on it, gives a scalar number (or the eigenvalue) times itself.
2. *Stationary state* : The state of a particle that does not vary with time.
3. *Bound state* : The state of a particle bounded by within a potential, meaning - the energy of the particle in that state is less than that of the potential.

Comment: I disagree that a stationary state is a state of a particle that doesn't vary with time.

Comment: @no_choice99 : May I rephrase it as ... 
"The probability of finding a particle in that state is independent of time"?

Comment: @FelaRenthlei This is not correct either. There is nothing stopping you having a state like the following:
$$|\psi \rangle = a(t) |E_0(t) \rangle +b(t) | E_1(t) \rangle$$ where the probabilities (e.g. $|a(t)|$)  and stationary states  (e.g. $|E_0(t)\rangle$) both vary with time.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification : OK. I agree with your answer as above, "time-independent expectation value" in that particular set of basis.